# else if change flow

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

I have a series of else if statements. Essentially I check if the data a user enters is valid. I have a text field where a user can enter the title of a deal. I check to make sure they have entered something. Then I want to make sure what they have entered is not just white space.

As you can see in my code when the user input is not valid I enter the else if and exit the method making sure the deal is not added.

However I have a problem. To see if a user has entered white space I must first work this out, but this is inside the else if.

Effectively my else if should be something along the lines of 'if there is white space then enter the else if and be returned'. But this is not possible as I don't know if there is white space.

Could anyone help with the flow as in where it could be placed?

My else if expression must essentially be true if there are white spaces.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
//checks if something has been entered. That something could be a space. If nothing is entered length is 0 and message is displayed
if (![self.dealTitleTextField.text length]> 0) {
    NSLog(@"Deal Title is empty");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not quite!" message:@"You haven't entered a title and you have to have one. Please do so." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return ;
}//start of new else you entered 18th august and needs to be reworked
else if ([self.dealTitleTextField.text length] > 0){
    NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmedString = [self.dealTitleTextField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
    if ([trimmedString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        // String contains only whitespace.
        NSLog(@"Deal Title is made up just of white space");
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not quite!" message:@"You haven't entered a title that is made up purely of white space. This isn't allowed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return ;
    }
    NSLog(@"Deal Title - End of check");
}
//end of new else you entered 18th august that needs to be reworked
else if (self.dealModel.dealTypeModel == NULL){
    NSLog(@"Deal Type is empty");
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Not quite!" message:@"You haven't entered a deal type and you have to have one. Please do so." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}else if (![self.dealDescriptionTextArea.text length]> 0){
    NSLog(@"Deal TextArea is empty");//more code below not included as out of scope
```

Comment: Too many `else`s.  Drop the `if` from the 2nd `else if` (it can only be `> 0`) and the 3rd `else if` is a separate test altogether so drop the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim the white spaces first.

Then you just need to check that the length isn't 0.

Don't differentiate between just white spaces and nothing. Over complicating it for the user I think. If they enter just white spaces then clear it back to nothing so they can type it again.

Also, your third and fourth `else if` blocks should be separate `if` statements.

Three sets of ifs.

```
Trim white space from title.
If deal title is length 0 then fail.
If deal type is null then fail.
If deal description is blank then fail.
```

They are not else ifs just ifs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this be should changed to:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [self.dealTitleTextField stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

if (trimmedString.length)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Note that there isn't a need to include > 0, as 0 will evaluate to NO and anything greater than 0 evaluates to YES.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function to check if a text is null or blank or only white space by this:

```
- (BOOL) isNullString : (NSString *)textString{
     if (textString == nil || textString == (id)[NSNull null] || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textString] length] == 0 || [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textString] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {
        return YES;
     }
     else{
        return NO;
     }
}
```

Comment: What is this good for? `[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textString]`

Comment: it is checking all nsstring like. Some time we are fetching data from websevice if there are null value it becomes a cfstring so its convert it to nsstring so it is use

Comment: `CFString` and `NSString` are interchangable. What is the actual problem there?

Comment: he is checking all thing in a else if so i write this to check in a place